# Problemas con la colisión de un rectángulo en una superficie

Tags: pygame

Bueno estoy intentando crear un juego de gestión y mi idea es crear un menu que no ocupe por completo la pantalla y que tenga un boton por cada estructura disponible, sin embargo cuando intento hacer que imprima una señal cuando el mouse pase sobre el, pero imprime la señal en una posicion fuera del menu, creo que es porque la posición del rectángulo del botón es (70, 70) y esta tomando en cuenta toda la pantalla en lugar de solamente el menu, he intentado usar pygame-menu pero me pareció bastante complejo para algunas acciones que deberian ser simples, tambien intente hacer el menu como una subsurface hija de la pantalla completa y el boton una subsurface hija del menu pero dió el mismo resultado, adjunto el codigo del menu y del boton para que lo corrijan y me puedan dar algunos consejos que como puedo corregirlo y de antemano les agradezco, y soy nuevo en esto asi que no se si sea conveniente tambien compartir el codigo del juego

```
import pygame
from .config import *
# el archivo config es para los colores y algunos valores predeterminados

class Boton(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, left, bottom):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(GREEN_LIGHT)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = left
        self.rect.bottom = bottom
```

```
import pygame
from .config import *
# el archivo config es para los colores y algunos valores predeterminados
from .boton import Boton

class menu(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, left, bottom):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((300, 300))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = left
        self.rect.bottom = bottom
        self.boton = Boton(70, 70)
        self.image.blit(self.boton.image, self.boton.rect)

    def update(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if self.boton.rect.collidepoint(mouse):
            print("Si")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés razón, las posiciones con las que estás trabajando, son relativas a la pantalla.

#### Solución más simple

Cuando quieras ubicar el botón dentro del menú, sumale a las coordenadas relativas al menú, las coordenadas en las que se ubica el menú en la pantalla. Esto lo podés hacer al crear el botón y tendrás que tenerlo en cuenta cada vez que muevas el botón de lugar usando posiciones absolutas.

```
self.boton = Boton(self.rect.left + 70, self.rect.top + 70)
```

El código anterior crea el botón en las coordenadas 70x 70y dentro del menú relativas a la esquina superior izquierda del menú.

#### La mejor solución (pero más compleja)

La idea que se me ocurre es crear una subclase de sprite llamada widget, que a su vez contenga un grupo de sprites o widgets. Este grupo será dibujado en el sprite al que pertenecen, de esa manera optimizando el juego para que no redibuje cada sprite al cohete.

Vamos procesando los eventos con un algoritmo e irlo pasando de widget en widget. Por ejemplo, en el caso de un evento de mouse, nos conviene ir usando la tecnica mencionada en la solución simple, pero restando para convertir la coordenada en relativa al widget, y repetirla hasta que lleguemos al widget que fue clicado.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo simple:

```
import pygame

class Widget(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *, rect, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        if(self.parent is not None):
            self.parent.children.add(self)

        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface(rect.size)
        self.rect = rect
        self.color = color
    
        self.children = pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates()

    def _on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        event.x -= self.rect.left
        event.y -= self.rect.top
        
        for sprite in self.children:
            if isinstance(sprite, Widget):
                if(sprite.rect.collidepoint((event.x, event.y))):
                    sprite._on_mouse_motion(event)
                    break
        else:
            self.on_mouse_motion(event)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        pass

    def repaint(self):
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.children.draw(self.image)

        if(self.parent is not None):
            self.parent.repaint()

    def update(self):
        self.children.update()
        

class Event:
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.pygame_event = event
        self.x, self.y = event.pos

class Button(Widget):
    def on_mouse_motion(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)

width = 800
height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

running = True

menu = Widget(rect = pygame.rect.Rect(100, 100, 200, 200),
              color = (200, 100, 0))

button = Button(menu,
                rect = pygame.rect.Rect(10, 10, 50, 50),
                color = (0, 255, 0))

button.repaint()

group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(menu)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION):
            group.sprite._on_mouse_motion(Event(event))

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    group.update()
    group.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

A esta versión le faltan varias cosas a implementar, pero sirve para dar una idea. Aun así, tengo la suposición de que el módulo pygame-menu ya implementa estas cosas.

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo hice de la manera sencilla para comprobar y aunque tuve que cambiar el rectangulo en el cual la imagen del boton es dibujada ahora si esta funcionando, tambien estoy intentado hacerlo de la manera compleja pero tengo algunas dudas, por ejemplo la clase Event, esa clase me confunde un porque no conozco muchos eventos de pygame que tengan una variable de posicion, asi que no se exactamente cual seria la utilidad de esa clase, gracias por anticipado

Comment: De nada! La clase event es un envoltorio sobre el evento de pygame. El punto sería tener datos del evento (como la posición relativa al widget) sin tener que modificar el evento original.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude lograr que funcionara solamente si se presiona el boton, pero otra duda que tengo es que supongo que la función on_mouse_motion() ademas de su objetivo en el programa tambien sirve como una referencia para que yo sepa en que punto debo programar las distintas funciones de los distintos widgets @Dante S.

Comment: Perdón la tardanza, dejé stack overflow por un tiempo. Me cuesta entenderte. Pero la idea es tener cada tipo de evento del widget en una función separada. De esa manera es mas facil de encontrar en código que corresponde al evento y manejarlo con más facilidad sin necesidad de un if-else